# Remove ads from Windows Live Messenger

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-messenger, advertisements

How can I remove the ads from Windows Live Messenger build 14.0.8089.726? Maybe there is a registry setting for that?

Googling this brings lots of results with some applications full of viruses and malware. Please suggest something that you have tried yourself (on Windows 7) and confirmed as successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [A-Patch](http://apatch.org/)? The latest update mentions that specific version you are talking about.

**Edit**: I just tried it on my Live Messenger Version 2009 (Build 14.0.80.89.726) on Windows 7, and I can confirm that it works.

Comment: I've successfully used A-patch with previous versions of Messenger and Windows. It's a good program with a lot of other features.